# How to pull data from multiple workbooks in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am working on designing a PARETO, and I need to pull data from multiple sheets via a single workbook.

So when someone opens this pareto, and push a button, a pareto will be created via the information on another workbook.

Is it possible to get that information without copying it all over?

In English, I have a workbook called Open Order, and another called PARETO. If I push a button in PARETO I want to have it pull data from Open Order, and say ok, 20% of all jobs in Open Order Archive sheet are late... is it possible to do this without having both books open or no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as one is open it can extract data from the other even when that is closed. BUt I would recommend opening both because extracting a lot of data this way can be (or at least used to be) VERY slow. Apparently each 'Lookup' opens a new instance and does not close it immediatley afterwards.